# What is the maximum number of attacks a single character can make in 1 round?

Tags: optimization, star-wars-saga-edition

### Introduction

A friend and I were discussing our builds for an upcoming venture into Star Wars: Saga Edition and we're dabbling with multiattack characters: one melee and one ranged, and need some input as to the rules.

### Questions

1. Given two different melee weapons (e.g. a vibroblade and a lightsaber), what is the maximum number of attacks a single character at 20th level can make in a single round, and how (i.e. which feats, talents and so forth, are used) do you achieve it?

   - **a.** If he is alone in the encounter?
   - **b.** Is he has allies that can provide benefits?
   - **c.** What is the highest possible to-hit-modifier to get for said attacks?
2. Given two different ranged weapons (e.g. a blaster pistol and a [insert exotic ranged one-handed weapon]), what is the maximum number of attacks a single character at 20th level can make in a single round, and how (i.e. which feats, talents and so forth, are used) do you achieve it?

   - **a.** If he is alone in the encounter?
   - **b.** Is he has allies that can provide benefits?
   - **c.** What is the highest possible to-hit-modifier to get for said attacks?

Comment: I realize it has been a while and this may not be important to you anymore, but if it is I must ask whether the character in question is duel-wielding any of the specified weapons and what class(es) they were considering being?

Comment: @DaveFY I'm asking for the highest amount of attacks possible within the entirety of the Saga Edition rules. If dual-wielding will increase the amount of attacks compared to single-wielding, then yes: they'll dual-wield, otherwise no. Classes does not factor into it. Any class that will help increase the amount of attacks/to-hit modifier of said attacks is encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have one handed weapons the answers are the same for ranged or melee with the details changing.

1. Four although opponents could draw other attacks.  That would be three from the Triple Attack feat (requires Double attack) in one of your weapons and an additional attack with an off-hand weapon.
2. It all depends on the allies and they kinds of benefits they can provide.
3. Triple Attack is a -10 penalty for ALL attacks.  Using a second weapon to attack is also a -10 penalty on ALL attacks.  The dual weapon penalties can be reduced with the Dual Weapon Mastery Feats I-III which drops the penalties to -5/-2/0.  Some PrC classes have access to "Multiattack Proficiency - weapon type" talents which reduced the penalties for making multiple attacks 2 points for each level takes so taken five times it will reduce the -10 penalty to 0 for that given weapon type.

Comment: Isnt it also higher when force abilities come into play? (or am I mistaken that there exists at least one that grants additional actions/attacks)?